# How do I select rows with 5 distinct values for each value in other columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, imdb

For reference, this is the schema of the table: casts (pid, mid, role)

What I want to do is find the pid(s) such that they have exactly 5 distinct roles in that mid. That is, since this is a table for actors where pid is the actor id, mid is the movie id and role is the role they play, I want to find all the actor ids that have exactly 5 distinct roles in the respective movie ids of which there can be more than one and that I also want these movie ids.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this without say like 5 self-joins but I'd rather not do that since that would be resource heavy.

[Sample table data(casts table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXgW5.png)

[Sample result from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1sU8.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add sample table data AND the exact output you expect.

Comment: I've done as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select pid, mid
from casts
group by pid, mid
having count(distinct role) = 5;
```